# IN pq.Array fails to pass values

Tags: postgresql, go

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const (
    DB_USER     = "<username>"
    DB_PASSWORD = "<password>"
    DB_NAME     = "<db>"
)

func main() {
    dbinfo := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)
    checkErr(err)
    defer db.Close()

    fmt.Println("# Querying with blacklist in SQL")
    rows, err := db.Query(`
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT x from (values ('A'), ('B'), ('C') ) s(x)
    ) As Res1 WHERE x NOT IN ('A');
`)
    checkErr(err)

    for rows.Next() {
        var str string
        err = rows.Scan(&str)
        fmt.Println(str) // Prints B,C
    }

    fmt.Println("Querying with blacklist in Golang")
    blacklist := []string{"A"}

    q := `
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT x from (values ('A'), ('B'), ('C') ) s(x)
    ) As Res1 WHERE x NOT IN ($1);

`
    rows, err = db.Query(q, pq.Array(blacklist))
    checkErr(err)

    for rows.Next() {
        var str string
        err = rows.Scan(&str)
        fmt.Println(str) // Prints A, B, C
    }
}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

where I pass a pq.Array as a parameter to a Golang Postgres format string $1. However the parameter fails to get passed. When I expect an output of `B,C`, the program is printing `A,B,C`.

```
# Querying with blacklist in SQL
B
C
Querying with blacklist in Golang
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres's [IN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR) does not take an array like for example [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21103) or [ALL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21126) which is where you can use `pq.Array`.

Instead of using `x NOT IN($1)` you can use `x <> ALL($1)`.

From [ALL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21126)'s docs.

> The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of
>   the array using the given operator, which must yield a Boolean result.
>   The result of ALL is "true" if all comparisons yield true (including
>   the case where the array has zero elements). The result is "false" if
>   any false result is found.